# List all employee with leave title, and leave apply in join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join, outer-join

I have three tables:

Table 1: **employee**

```
emp_id -KEY    emp_name    emp_join_date
 1841           test       2016-04-01
 1842           test1      2019-04-01
```

Table 2: **leave_set**

```
emp_id-KEY    start_date    end_date    nod    leave_type_id
 1841         2019-04-01    2019-04-02   2         2
```

Table 3: **leave_type**

```
leave_type_id-KEY    leave_title
    1                   AL
    2                   SL
    3                   CME
```

I tried left join but if `leave_set` has no values then it return null values in `Leave_Set` and `leave_type`.

```
   SELECT 
       O.emp_id,  
       P.leave_title, I.leave_type_id, I.nod
   FROM 
       employee O 
   LEFT JOIN 
       leave_set I ON O.emp_id = I.emp_id and o.emp_id=1841
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       leave_type P ON P.leave_type_id = I.leave_type_id
```

My output looks like this:

```
emp_id  leave_title   nod
1841    NULL          NULL
1879    NULL          NULL
```

I need output like below:

```
emp_id   Leave_title  nod
1841     AL           -
1841     SL           2
1841     CME          -
1842     AL           -
1842     SL           -
1842     CME          -
```

I need each employee with all `leave_title` with `nod` whether they apply `leave_set`.

Comment: @DaleBurrell sample data updated..

Comment: @Dolubolu The problem is if Leave_Set doesn't have a row, then you can't get the nod or the leave_title as that table is used to join the 3 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `cross join` with `leave_type` because you want all combinations. Followed by a `left join` of the actual leave record e.g.

```
select O.emp_id, P.leave_title, I.leave_type_id, I.nod
from employee O 
cross join leave_type P 
left join leave_set I ON O.emp_id = I.emp_id and I.leave_type_id = P.leave_type_id
where o.emp_id = 1841
```

PS: You would normally restrict to the employee in question in the `where` clause, not the `join`.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that employees could take the same leave type multiple times.

If so, you may really want an aggregation query:

```
select e.emp_id, lt.leave_title, 
       sum(ls.nod) as nod
from employee e cross join
     leave_type lt left join
     leave_set ls
     on ls.emp_id = e.emp_id and
        ls.leave_type_id = lt.leave_type_id
group by e.emp_id, lt.leave_title
order by e.emp_id, lt.leave_title;
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqPvU.png)

select  em.emp_id,lt.leave_title,ls.nod from leave_type lt cross join employee em left join leave_set ls on ls.leave_type_id=lt.leave_type_id